# Add to list instead of replacing contents on click

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I am creating a pizza form which will display what the customer is ordering by pressing the buttons. My idea is the customer clicks the size of item they want to order and it will be displayed on the side.

### Problems

I happen to be new to JavaScript, but I don't understand why when I click the buttons they only add one of the items and when I click another one they replace each other. I want to change it so they can be clicked infinitely. Also I want to know if there is a more productive version of my code.

```
<table>
      <tr id="top_border">
        <th>Pizzas</th><th>Small</th><th>Medium</th><th>Large</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pepperoni</td><td><span onclick="ADDpps()">4.99</span></td><td>5.15</td><td>6.70</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Meat Lovers</td><td><span onclick="ADDmlps()">4.99</span></td><td>5.15</td><td>6.70</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Hawaiian</td><td><span onclick="ADDhps()">4.99</span></td>     <td>5.15</td><td>6.70</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Output

```
<ul id="items">
</ul>
<ul id="price">
</ul>
```

Javascript I tried to use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mlps= ["S - Meat lovers pizza","$4.99"];
function ADDmlps(){
    document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = mlps[0];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = mlps[1];
}
var hps = ["S - Hawaiian Pizza","$4.99"];
function ADDhps(){
    document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = hps[0];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = hps[1];
}
var pps = ["S - Pepperoni Pizza","$4.99"];
function ADDpps(){
    document.getElementById("items").innerHTML = pps[0];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = pps[1];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your replacing all the contents of the `#items` and `#price` divs by setting their `innerHTML`. You'll want to use the DOM to add a [new `<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to the `<ul>` on each function call.

Instead of having tons of variables hanging around that store similar pieces of data you should make each pizza have a `price` and `name` property in an object. Then each object can be an item in an array:

```
var pizzas = [
  {
    name: "S - Meat lovers pizza",
    price: "$4.99"
  }
  // ...
];
```

You also want to condense your functions that do very similar things into 1:

```
// call passing the index of the pizza in the pizzas array
function addPizza(index) {
  var pizza = pizzas[index];
  var name = pizza.name;
  var price = pizza.price;
  // now add an <li> to each <ul> with this info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new `<li>` on each click rather than replacing the entire list's innerHTML.

What about something like this to start off with:

```js
var mlps= ["S - Meat lovers pizza","$4.99"];
function ADDmlps(){
  createItem(mlps[0], mlps[1]);
}
var hps = ["S - Hawaiian Pizza","$4.99"];
function ADDhps(){
  createItem(hps[0], hps[1]);
}
var pps = ["S - Pepperoni Pizza","$4.99"];
function ADDpps(){
  createItem(pps[0], pps[1]);
}

function createItem(item, price) {
  var itemLi = document.createElement('li');
  itemLi.class = "item";
  itemLi.innerHTML = item + " : " + price;
  
  document.getElementById("items").appendChild(itemLi);
}
```

```html
<table>
     <tr id="top_border">
      <th>Pizzas</th><th>Small</th><th>Medium</th><th>Large</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pepperoni</td><td><span onclick="ADDpps()">4.99</span></td><td>5.15</td><td>6.70</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Meat Lovers</td><td><span onclick="ADDmlps()">4.99</span></td><td>5.15</td><td>6.70</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Hawaiian</td><td><span onclick="ADDhps()">4.99</span></td>     <td>5.15</td><td>6.70</td>
     </tr>
</table>

<ul id="items">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it happens, because you used equals sign (`=`) which replaces whole content of the variable `.innerHTML`.

```js
var a = "test";
a = "2"; // 2
a = "3"; // 3

// vs.

var b = "test";
b += "2"; // test2
b += "3"; // test23
```

Also, you may want to use an actual `button` HTML element instead of adding this action to `span`. Using non-button elements for defining actions can confuse or break functionality for some users.